# Having trouble implementing z-index for overlapped tooltip component React, Tailwind and DaisyUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, daisyui

I hope you all are doing well. I have a question regarding this fireship io tutorial implementing TailwindCSS and DaisyUI in React.

I've created a side navbar like that of discord with tooltips that appear as spans to the side as you hover over them.

The issue is, The tooltips appear below the component that exists to the right of it, The components to the right are a set of cards provided by DaisyUI.

I have tried to implement Tailwind's custom z-index for the tooltips, the card components, and for the components that encapsulate them both respectively to no avail.

**Card Component Z Index**

```
<div className="card-body z-[-99999]">
              {firstName + " " + lastName}
              <h2 className="card-title">{}</h2>
              <p>Click the button to listen on Spotiwhy app.</p>
              <div className="card-actions justify-center">
                <button className="btn btn-primary bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-500 border-transparant ">
                  Listen
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Tool Tip Component**

```
const SideBarIcon = ({ icon, text = "tooltip " }) => (
  <div className="sidebar-icon group">
    {icon}
    <span class="sidebar-tooltip group-hover:scale-100 z-[99999]">{text}</span>
  </div>
);
```

Is there some implementation detail that I'm missing?

I have it set up where I run npm from vs code and I access the app from firefox

I'm really trying to get a hang of firebase react design and anything helps.

Cheers,

Tutorial Source Code: https://github.com/fireship-io/tailwind-dashboard

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Landing from "./components/landing";
import SideBar from "./components/sidebar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App flex">
      <SideBar className="z-[99999]" />
      <div className="content-main z-[0]">
        <Landing className="z-[-99999]" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Landing.js**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Divider } from "./SpacingComponents";
import axios from "axios";

export const Landing = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(null);
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios
      .get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then((res) => {
        //console.log("Getting Data: ", res.data.results[0].name.first);
        setFirstName(res.data.results[0].name.first);
        setLastName(res.data.results[0].name.last);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-5xl">Accounted</h1>
      <Divider />
      <div className="grid gap-6 lg:grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-3 sm:grid-cols-2 transition-all duration-100">
        {[...Array(50)].map((x, i) => (
          <div className="card lg:card-side bg-base-100 shadow-xl z-[-99999]">
            <figure>
              {!isLoading ? (
                <img
                  className="transition-all ease-linear z-[-99999]"
                  style={{}}
                  src={"https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=" + i}
                  alt="Album"
                />
              ) : (
                <svg
                  class="animate-spin h-5 w-5 mr-3"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                ></svg>
              )}
            </figure>
            <div className="card-body z-[-99999]">
              {firstName + " " + lastName}
              <h2 className="card-title">{}</h2>
              <p>Click the button to listen on Spotiwhy app.</p>
              <div className="card-actions justify-center">
                <button className="btn btn-primary bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-500 border-transparant ">
                  Listen
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Divider />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Landing;
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
import { BsPlus, BsFillCloudLightningFill, BsGearFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaPoo, FaSun, FaMoon } from "react-icons/fa";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Divider } from "./SpacingComponents";

export const SideBar = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
      setTheme("dark");
    } else {
      setTheme("light");
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme === "dark") {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }, [theme]);

  const handleThemeSwitch = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark");
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="fixed top-0 left-0 h-screen 
      w-16 m-0 flex flex-col
     bg-gray-100 text-black shadow-lg
     dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-white transition-color
     duration-100 ease-linear items-center"
    >
      <SideBarIcon icon={<BsPlus size={"28"} />} />
      <SideBarIcon icon={<BsFillCloudLightningFill size={"28"} />} />
      <SideBarIcon icon={<FaPoo size={"28"} />} />
      <SideBarIcon icon={<BsGearFill size={"28"} />} />
      <Divider className="divider" />
      <button
        className="btn btn-circle darkmode-toggle"
        onClick={handleThemeSwitch}
      >
        {theme === "dark" ? <FaMoon /> : <FaSun />}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const SideBarIcon = ({ icon, text = "tooltip " }) => (
  <div className="sidebar-icon group">
    {icon}
    <span class="sidebar-tooltip group-hover:scale-100">{text}</span>
  </div>
);

export default SideBar;
```

**SpacingComponents.js**

```
export const Divider = () => <div className="divider"></div>;
```

**Index.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .sidebar-icon {
    @apply relative flex items-center justify-center
    h-12 w-12 mt-2 mb-2 mx-auto shadow-lg 
    bg-gray-300 
    dark:bg-gray-800 
    text-green-600
    dark:text-green-500
    hover:bg-green-600 
    dark:hover:bg-green-600 
    hover:text-black 
    dark:hover:text-white 
    rounded-3xl hover:rounded-xl transition-all
    duration-100 ease-linear cursor-pointer;
  }
  .sidebar-tooltip {
    @apply absolute w-auto p-2 m-2 min-w-max left-14 rounded-md shadow-md
   
    bg-gray-300 
    dark:bg-gray-900 
    text-black
    dark:text-white
    hover:dark:text-white 
   
    z-[99999]
    text-xs font-bold 
    transition-all duration-100 scale-0 origin-left;
  }
  .darkmode-toggle {
    @apply relative flex items-center justify-center w-6 h-6 shadow-md 
    bg-gray-300 
    text-green-500 
    hover:text-black 
    dark:bg-gray-800 
    hover:dark:text-white 
    hover:bg-green-600 
    dark:hover:bg-green-600 
    rounded-3xl transition-all duration-100 
    ease-linear cursor-pointer
    ;
  }

  .card {
    @apply 
    dark:hover:bg-gray-500 
    dark:bg-gray-600
    z-0
    
    
    transition-all duration-100 origin-left;
  } 

  .divider{
    @apply dark:bg-gray-500 h-0.5 rounded-2xl;
  }


  .content-main{
    @apply ml-16 mr-4 p-5
    ;
  }

  .App{
    @apply bg-gray-300 dark:bg-gray-800 text-black dark:text-gray-400 text-center;
  }
}
```

I've applied the custom z-index from tailwind by utilizing the extreme boundaries in terms z-[-99999] and z-[99999] for the different components. I've also attempted to rearrange the components in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove shadow-xl from your cards

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).